# Complexity of representing all satisfying assignments

Tags: computational-complexity, boolean-algebra, satisfiability, decision-problems

I am not formally educated in Complexity Theory hence asking this question. In which complexity class should the problem of representing all satisfying assignments of a Boolean system (equivalently a Boolean formula) belong? This is not a decision problem because we want to know all satisfying assignments. Also this not a counting problem because the set of all satisfying assignments can be far bigger than the set of partial assignments (such as those defined by implicants of the formula) which represents all satisfying assignments.

Comment: Do you mean, given a boolean function $f: \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}$, output the set $\{x : f(x) = 1\}$?

Comment: Not exactly, I need to output a set of implicants t of f which are elementary conjunctions of literals x_i or x_i' such that f(x)=1 iff t(x)=1. Such a set can be much smaller than the set of all satisfying assgnments.

Comment: Ok, as I understand, in my question I am asking what is the complexity class of writing a DNF for a Boolean formula. This is because once the DNF expression is written each of the terms is an implicant and the set of all terms represent all satisfying assignments of the formula. In general it is well known that the number of DNF is exponential. Hence the time complexity is in general exponential. Can such a problem be classified within the known complexity classes which describe decision problems or counting problems? This is a clarification to my question.